# Java добавление потоков Queue

Tags: java, очередь

У меня два класса, один ставит переменную в очередь другой забирает. Реализовать не могу, подскажите пожалуйста что не так? В  Java совсем еще новичок.

КЛАСС№1

```java
package jdev.services;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;

@Service
public class DataPeekService  {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( DataPeekService.class );

    private BlockingDeque<Object> queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Object>( 100 );
    private int putCount;
    private long previous;
   
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1_000)
    void put() throws InterruptedException {
        int i = 5;
        queue.put( i );
 
}
```

КЛАСС№2

```java
package jdev.services;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;


@Service
public class DataSendService extends DataPeekService {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataPeekService.class);

    private BlockingDeque<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(100);
    private int putCount;
    private long previous;

    @Autowired
    private DataPeekService dataPeekService;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1_000)
    void take() throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("take tingai !!");
    
        System.out.println( "Данные :" );
        System.out.println(" ScheduledQueueService.take " + queue.poll());
    }

}
```

Comment: У вас два класса и у каждого своя очередь.

Comment: Вы просто чудо. С меня Пузырь. Я 10 дней мучался. Спасибо огромное.

Comment: на здоровье! Хорошо, что разобрались.